# Replace ONLY the first occurrence of a string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to update all phone numbers that start with 00 by replacing the 00 with a '+' prefix.
I must replace only the first occurrence of 00 and nothing else.

```
phone_number:     000258843300081
ActualResult:     +02588433+081
ExpectedResult:   +0258843300081
```

*Incorrect Query Used:*

```
    UPDATE [dbo].[phone]
    SET phone_number = REPLACE(phone_number, '00', '+')
    WHERE phone_number_numeric LIKE '00%'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the correct query. Just convert to an update command!
Also, I've used a generic approach to solve the problem.

```
    SELECT 
      phone_number
    , STUFF(phone_number, CHARINDEX('00', phone_number), LEN('00'), '+') as ExpectedResult
    FROM dbo.phone 
    WHERE phone_number_numeric LIKE '00%'
```

The `REPLACE` function looks at the entire string. Use `STUFF` function to narrow the scope down to the desired limit.

Comment: Why not the 1 and 2 in the parameters like in the answer by @Gordon Linoff?

Comment: @JamesZ: For the sake of clarity, some would surely wonder what 1 and 2 stand for. This explains itself!

Comment: @JamesZ - Yes! "[Magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad)" should be avoided in code.

Comment: Very useful, thank you! This is a better solution for me as I'm not replacing "00". I'm replacing a country code from a joined table which varies in length!

Answer (score 3):

Just use `STUFF()`:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[phone]
    SET phone_number = STUFF(phone_number, 1, 2, '+')
    WHERE phone_number_numeric LIKE '00%';
```